# HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported Issue On Firefox

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox, audio

Please check this url:

http://www.foodworlds.info/music/

after click on buttons (except the red one) should play small sound. However, It is working on my '**pc firefox/chrome**' and '**Mac chrome**'. However, on **mac firefox** its throwing an error in firebug as like the below screen:

[image]

Anybody has idea how its happening so and how to get this resolved please?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to add additional audio file formats for your `<audio>` tag in order to support more platforms and browsers:

```
<audio class="blue" controls>
  <source src="audio/test1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="audio/test1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

It will also require you to place relevant resources on the server (`audio/test1.ogg` in this case). There are a lot of online convertors (like http://media.io/) that may help you with converting files to other formats.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility) :

> To avoid patent issues, support for MPEG 4, H.264, MP3 and AAC is not built directly into Firefox. Instead it relies on support from the OS or hardware.

So using firefox, the support of some file formats like mp3 does not only depend on the browser version but also on the OS.

Answer (score -1):

> Solve this by installing missing codecs in Ubuntu by sudo apt-get
>   install ubuntu-restricted-extras