# Sound effect not working on jQuery popup

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery popup code but I also need to play sound when popup is opened.  The jQuery popup opens but sound doesn't play [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RuuQH/14/)

Code:

```
function lightbox() {
    $.colorbox({
        inline: true,
        width: "26%",
        height: "85%",
        href: "#inline_content",
        overlayClose: false
    });
}

function loadSound() {
    lightbox();
    document.jukebox.play();
}
```

Markup:

```
<embed src="skype.mp3" autostart='true' hidden='true' loop='true' name="jukebox">
<div style='display:none%;' id="content">
    <div id='inline_content' style='padding:0px; padding-bottom:0px;'></div>
</div> <a href="javascript:loadSound();">click</a>
```

Comment: Please don't. Users hate this. Also, can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: ya..i know but client needs that

Comment: here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RuuQH/14/

Comment: You have several javascript errors on the page, fix those and add an absolute path to the sound.

Comment: see.. only alert is working here no sound playing http://jsfiddle.net/f4vhc/34/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the tag you are using and the parameters you are setting. You need to use an `audio` tag instead. Here is a working demo:

EDIT: In order to handle multiple browsers, different formats will be needed. The combination of OGG and MP3 should handle all modern browsers. [Native Audio in the Browser | HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/amMdT/1/)

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you make sure that the audio had preloaded? Did you get any javascript errors? Give a little more information.

Comment: HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource http://safiamusic.com/somgs/safia11.mp3 failed.

Comment: What browser are you using? This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16761033/1669208

Comment: I updated my answer. This has to do with licensing of formats. Firefox does not support MP3. You can convert using [Audacity](audacity.sourceforge.net) or an online resource.

Comment: i need to stop the audio when popup is closed how can i do that??

Comment: where to add it...i think in  jquery popup but dont know where

Comment: Just add a callback to the lightbox.

Comment: we need to use `.pause()` instead of `.stop()`